Dell G3 15 integrated webcam not working on Ubuntu 24.04
I've tried searching for this problem quite extensively but haven't found anything specific to my problem.
Basically, since recently my integrated webcam has stopped working on my Dell G3 3590 laptop. At first it still worked sometimes but now I haven't been able to get it working for several days.
What I've tried:

Installing cheese
reinstalling drivers with sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-image-$(uname -r)
Other posts suggest certain drivers but these are all for other manufacturers (most notably Intel MIPI)
My webcam does not have a shutter button

At first it did not show up in v4l2-ctl --list-devices and inxi -Fxz showed Device-3: Microdia USB 2.0 Camera driver: N/A type: USB bus-ID: 1-5:4. I assumed this was a driver issue, so I reinstalled my drivers and also disabled secure boot.
Now it does show up, however when attempting ffplay -f video4linux2 /dev/video0, It shortly flashes the camera LED but exits with [video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x7e2f80000c80] ioctl(VIDIOC_STREAMON): Protocol error /dev/video0: Protocol error. Attempting it again, results in a Input/output error.
I was able to enable secure boot again without this changing.
Here are some command outputs that might be relevant:
https://pastebin.com/sBjpBUXU
Important to note is that the Vendor changed from Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. to the random string that it is now after reinstalling my drivers and disabling secure boot.
The ID in lsusb also changed from Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6363 Microdia USB 2.0 Camera originally.
Update: This morning, the webcam decided to work again (I literally did not change anything since yesterday), so I took the opportunity to run all the commands again. They're in this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/cfeHP6LD
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a67:c006 Medeli Electronics Co., Ltd K66
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:671f Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c08b Logitech, Inc. G502 SE HERO Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 25a7:fa70 Areson Technology Corp 2.4G Wireless Receiver
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1a40:0801 Terminus Technology Inc. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 258a:00c8 SINO WEALTH RK Bluetooth Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

$ inxi -Gxz
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] vendor: Dell
    driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-9.5 bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q] vendor: Dell
    driver: nvidia v: 535.183.01 arch: Pascal bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-3: Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD driver: uvcvideo type: USB
    bus-ID: 1-5:4
  Display: x11 server: X.org v: 1.21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver:
    X: loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa dri: iris
    gpu: i915,nvidia,nvidia-nvswitch resolution: 1: 1920x1080 2: 1920x1080
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: nvidia,swrast platforms:
    active: surfaceless,device inactive: gbm,wayland,x11,device-1,device-2
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.3
    note: incomplete (EGL sourced) renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2,
    llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6 256 bits)

part of $sudo lshw -C multimedia
  *-usb:2
       description: Video
       product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
       vendor: CN0M1RXT8LG009ADCMY1A01
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@1:5
       version: 85.02
       capabilities: usb-2.01
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s

$ sudo dmesg | grep 1-5
[    1.853917] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.013651] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=671f, bcdDevice=85.02
[    2.013685] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.013692] usb 1-5: Product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
[    2.013698] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: CN0M1RXT8LG009ADCMY1A01
[   12.161915] usb 1-5: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (0c45:671f)

$ sudo lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/001/004
Device: ID 0c45:671f Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 [unknown]
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0c45 Microdia
  idProduct          0x671f Integrated_Webcam_HD
  bcdDevice           85.02
  iManufacturer           2 CN0M1RXT8LG009ADCMY1A01
  iProduct                1 Integrated_Webcam_HD
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x02c1
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    ** UNRECOGNIZED:  28 ff 42 49 53 54 00 01 06 01 10 00 00 00 00 00 d1 10 d0 07 d2 11 f4 01 d3 12 f4 01 d4 13 f4 01 d5 14 d0 07 d6 15 f4 01
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               5 Integrated Webcam
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 Integrated Webcam
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.00
        wTotalLength       0x0067
        dwClockFrequency       15.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             5
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               4
        iTerminal               0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                26
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 3
        guidExtensionCode         {28f03370-6311-4a2e-ba2c-6890eb334016}
        bNumControls            8
        bNrInPins               1
        baSourceID( 0)          2
        bControlSize            1
        bmControls( 0)       0x9f
        iExtension              0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                26
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 4
        guidExtensionCode         {0fb885c3-68c2-4547-90f7-8f47579d95fc}
        bNumControls            8
        bNrInPins               1
        baSourceID( 0)          3
        bControlSize            1
        bmControls( 0)       0xcf
        iExtension              0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iTerminal               0 
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x0020000e
          Auto-Exposure Mode
          Auto-Exposure Priority
          Exposure Time (Absolute)
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
      Warning: Descriptor too short
        bUnitID                 2
        bSourceID               1
        wMaxMultiplier          0
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls     0x0000177f
          Brightness
          Contrast
          Hue
          Saturation
          Sharpness
          Gamma
          White Balance Temperature
          Backlight Compensation
          Gain
          Power Line Frequency
          White Balance Temperature, Auto
        iProcessing             0 
        bmVideoStandards     0x00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               6
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            15
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  1 (INPUT_HEADER)
        bNumFormats                         2
        wTotalLength                   0x01a3
        bEndpointAddress                 0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmInfo                              0
        bTerminalLink                       5
        bStillCaptureMethod                 0
        bTriggerSupport                     0
        bTriggerUsage                       0
        bControlSize                        1
        bmaControls( 0)                     0
        bmaControls( 1)                     0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            11
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  6 (FORMAT_MJPEG)
        bFormatIndex                        1
        bNumFrameDescriptors                5
        bFlags                              0
          Fixed-size samples: No
        bDefaultFrameIndex                  1
        bAspectRatioX                       0
        bAspectRatioY                       0
        bmInterlaceFlags                 0x00
          Interlaced stream or variable: No
          Fields per frame: 1 fields
          Field 1 first: No
          Field pattern: Field 1 only
        bCopyProtect                        0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         1
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1280
        wHeight                           720
        dwMinBitRate                442368000
        dwMaxBitRate                442368000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1843789
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         2
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            960
        wHeight                           540
        dwMinBitRate                248832000
        dwMaxBitRate                248832000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1037389
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         3
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            848
        wHeight                           480
        dwMinBitRate                195379200
        dwMaxBitRate                195379200
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      814669
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         4
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           480
        dwMinBitRate                147456000
        dwMaxBitRate                147456000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      614989
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         5
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           360
        dwMinBitRate                110592000
        dwMaxBitRate                110592000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      461389
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            27
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  4 (FORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFormatIndex                        2
        bNumFrameDescriptors                7
        guidFormat                            {32595559-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71}
        bBitsPerPixel                      16
        bDefaultFrameIndex                  1
        bAspectRatioX                       0
        bAspectRatioY                       0
        bmInterlaceFlags                 0x00
          Interlaced stream or variable: No
          Fields per frame: 2 fields
          Field 1 first: No
          Field pattern: Field 1 only
        bCopyProtect                        0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         1
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1280
        wHeight                           720
        dwMinBitRate                147456000
        dwMaxBitRate                147456000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1843200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval        1000000
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)           1000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         2
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           480
        dwMinBitRate                147456000
        dwMaxBitRate                147456000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      614400
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         3
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           360
        dwMinBitRate                110592000
        dwMaxBitRate                110592000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      460800
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         4
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            424
        wHeight                           240
        dwMinBitRate                 48844800
        dwMaxBitRate                 48844800
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      203520
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         5
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            320
        wHeight                           240
        dwMinBitRate                 36864000
        dwMaxBitRate                 36864000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      153600
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         6
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            320
        wHeight                           180
        dwMinBitRate                 27648000
        dwMaxBitRate                 27648000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      115200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         7
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            160
        wHeight                           120
        dwMinBitRate                  9216000
        dwMaxBitRate                  9216000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize       38400
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             6
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                 13 (COLORFORMAT)
        bColorPrimaries                     1 (BT.709,sRGB)
        bTransferCharacteristics            1 (BT.709)
        bMatrixCoefficients                 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601))
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0080  1x 128 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0100  1x 256 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       3
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0320  1x 800 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       4
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0b20  2x 800 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       5
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x1320  3x 800 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       6
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x1400  3x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               1
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x0021
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  Platform Device Capability:
    bLength                28
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      5
    bReserved               0
    PlatformCapabilityUUID    {d8dd60df-4589-4cc7-9cd2-659d9e648a9f}
    CapabilityData[0]    0x00
    CapabilityData[1]    0x00
    CapabilityData[2]    0x00
    CapabilityData[3]    0x0a
    CapabilityData[4]    0x06
    CapabilityData[5]    0x03
    CapabilityData[6]    0x01
    CapabilityData[7]    0x00
Device Status:     0x0002
  (Bus Powered)
  Remote Wakeup Enabled


Update:
This morning, the webcam decided to work again (I literally did not change anything since yesterday), so I took the opportunity to run all the commands again. They're in this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/cfeHP6LD
